# What is the equivalent of |= in Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the equivalent of the |= operator in Visual Basic? For example (C#):

`flags |= MyEnum.SomeFlag`

Comment: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html I am not sure about the compound, but you are looking for 'bitwise or'. It's a funny bit of overloading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`flags = flags Or MyEnum.SomeFlag`

Comment: So you've got to use the long way? There's no operator like `Or=` or anything? :(

Comment: No there is not.  See the link I posted for more details in MSDN.

Comment: @Jake Petroules a 'ByRef' function? ;-)

Comment: Jake: Only the symbol (non-English-words) operators get the compound assignment variant. And even then, I believe those operators are fairly recent.

Comment: there's no short way in VB and VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

In C#, |= is the [Or assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx).

There's no equivalent operator in VB.

See the list of [Assignment Operators (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3466w64d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic does not support compound assignment operators as shown in the C# sample.  You'll need to use the expanded form of the assignment and the vb version of the bitwise or operator (simple `Or`)

```
flags = flags Or MyEnum.SomeFlag
```

Answer (score 0):

`flags = flags Or MyEnum.SomeFlag`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is any sort of official source, but check out these pages:

- http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Operators/2/
- http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Operators/3/

It seems to me that there isn't an existing combination of the bitwise-or-plus-assignment operator in VB.NET.  But there is a bitwise-or operator, and an assignment operator, which you can combine manually:

```
flags = flags Or MyEnum.SomeFlag
```

Comment: The `&=` operation is string concatenation, not a bitwise op.

Comment: @Gabe: Good info.  I don't program in that language, I just use google ;)  Will remove it from my answer